# Cannot Connect To RDS Instance Using Python pymysql Library

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pymysql

I am attempting to connect to an RDS instance using Python's pymysql library.  Unfortunately I'm getting an exception back.

Here is my Python code:

```python
import pymysql

#Connect
connection = pymysql.connect(host='jdbc:mysql://dbname.url.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/dbname',
                             port='3306',
                             user='username',
                             password='pass',
                             database='dbname')
```

Upon executing it, I receive the following exception:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/file/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    database='treemigodb')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 327, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 629, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'jdbc:mysql://dbname.url.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/dbname' ([Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known)")
```

Here is what I've tried:

- I've opened up the security group on the AWS side to traffic.  I had previously performed this connection in Java, with success.  AWS is configured as it should be.
- I've seen in other examples that the `host` format tends to vary.  Therefore, I've tried:
  `jdbc:mysql://dbname.url.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/dbname`

  `jdbc:mysql://url.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/dbname`

  `jdbc:mysql://dbname.url.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/`

  `jdbc:mysql://url.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/`

  `dbname.url.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/dbname`

  `url.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/dbname`

  `dbname.url.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/`

Is there some potential setup that I could be missing?  I've double-checked that every other parameter matches.

Comment: Where is the Python code running, inside the same VPC as the RDS instance? Or from outside the VPC? If outside, is the "Publicly Accessible" flag enabled on the RDS instance?

Comment: Should have mentioned that - I'm running it outside of the VPC from my local machine.  "Publicly Accessible" flag is enabled.

Comment: I think you should either remove the trailing `/dbname` from the hostname, or not specify a `database` parameter. Actually I believe host should just be `dbname.url.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: That worked, I also had to make my port value a digit instead of a string ('3306' -> 3306).  Odd how specific that is.  Thanks!